# How to Program an Indicator into the Unity Panel

Tags: libraries, appmenu, source-code, open-source

I'm working on an open source project and want to edit up one of the notifications for Ubuntu and install it into the Unity Panel (top black bar). How would I go about doing this? What files do I need to look at and what do I need to look for to edit? What language would I need to know? Anybody out there willing to point me in the right direction?

I should clarify. The notification is already made. I just want to make code that would upon installation move it into the notification bar. Thanks again guys.

update: So I found this little diddy right [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Unity_Architecture.pdf). By looking at the system architecture I can get a rough idea of what to be looking for. The problem now is that I cannot seem to find libindicator. Anybody got a clue?